# D3 Chart moves when buttonclick

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

im working on a d3 chart using a grouped chart from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

I can display them and I want to change my data when clicking one of the buttons.

Therefore, I'm calling my dataSet function "onclick"-ing one of the buttons. 
The functions erases all svg elements and then writes new ones so it kind of updates the data. It actually does work, but every time I click a button, the chart moves down. I don't really know why. Please help! Here's my Javascript code:

```
function dataSet(data){
d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();

var margin = {top: 40, right: 110, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = 1080 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#EEC591", "#CDAA7D", "#FF7F50", "#FF7256", "#EE6A50", "#EE6A50", "#CD5B45"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv(data, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Education"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Education; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Rating");

  var Education = svg.selectAll(".Education")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "Education")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Education) + ",0)"; });

  Education.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width+90)
      .attr("y", 310)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 80)
      .attr("y", 320)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});
}
```

And heres the html button part:

```
<div>
<input type="button" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" onclick="dataSet('data.csv')" />
<label for="radio1">Financial Situation</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"onclick="dataSet('datatest.csv')"/>
<label for="radio2">Accomodation</label>
</div>
```

I just want to update my input data :/
Here's also what it looks like, the bar chart should be at the top: 
[How it looks like after pressing a Butten on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUHOc.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's because you're adding a new `svg` element to `body` on every function call. You probably want to change this line `d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();` to be more specific. For example, `d3.select("#dataset-1-svg").remove()` where `#dataset-1-svg` is the id of the svg element you want to update/remove.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Isn't there a method to somehow clear body? I want to update the bars but if i call d3.select("rect").remove() or d3.selectAll("rect").remove() it just erases one bar per click, and does not update the new data. 
To specify: I'm reading the data.csv and by clicking accomodation, i want to erase the old bar and draw a new one with the data of datatest.csv

Comment: ah Sorry i needed to select Education here! Thank you so much!